# Add to offsetHeight of entire class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I have a page with elements in one class of variable heights based on the size of the text content of them. On page load I need to add 20px to the height of all of them.

```
var visibleposts = document.getElementsByClassName("post-contain");
   for(var i =0; i <= visibleposts.length; i++){
     visibleposts[i].style.height = visibleposts[i].offsetHeight + 20 + "px";
   }
```

That's the code I used. I put that inside of an `init()` function that runs on page load. However, I'm not sure how well that's working since it's running on a meteor server. I have it onload of the body. Like so:

```
<head>
  <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
</body>

<template name="FullFeed">
  {{#each posts}}
<!--    <a href="whenisay://{{adjective}}/{{noun}}/{{user}}/{{likes}}/{{date}}/{{_id}}">-->
    <a href="UnLiked.png">
      <div class="post-contain">
        <div class="chant">When I say <span class="varline">{{adjective}}</span> you say <span class="varline">{{noun}}</span></div>
<!--
        <div class="author-box">
          <p>By {{user}}<span class="spacer"> - </span>
            <img class="heart" src="UnLiked.png" onclick="console.log('hello');"/>
          </p>
        </div>
-->
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="author-box">
      <p>By {{user}}<span class="spacer"> - </span>
        <img class="heart" src="UnLiked.png" onclick="console.log('hello');"/>
      </p>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

If you want to debug it, it's running at http://whensayfeed.meteor.com

Answer (score 0):

As [humble.rumble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4639281/humble-rumble) mentioned in the comment, your code is not working, because at the time body is loaded, there are not yet any ".post-contain" divs generated by the template FullFeed.

You should not execute the code to modify the template-generated DOM immediately in main.js, but <del>use the [Template.myTemplate.onRendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) callback registering function.</del> *Update:* Template.myTemplate.onRendered from Meteor does not wait for individual data being loaded. There are many solutions how to attach a callback after all items have been loaded. See other StackOveflow questions:

- [How to execute helper function after DOM is ready in meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312812/how-to-execute-helper-function-after-dom-is-ready-in-meteor)
- [Running a function AFTER a meteor template is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615327/running-a-function-after-a-meteor-template-is-updated)
- [Callback when all Template items finished rendering in Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548581/callback-when-all-template-items-finished-rendering-in-meteor)
- [Meteor : wait until all templates are rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766341/meteor-wait-until-all-templates-are-rendered)

However, none of those are seamless and reasonably simple. That is why you can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead. In your case, you want to observe for added `<a/>` items into `<body/>`, then find `.post-contain`:

```
new MutationObserver(function (mutations){
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation){
        $(mutation.addedNodes).each(function (){
            if (this.localName == "a")
                var myNewDiv = $(".post-contain",this)[0]
        });
    });
}).observe($("body")[0], {childList: true});
```

As I'm not familiar with the Template API, it is possible that Template global variable is not available until the document has been loaded, in which case you'd use JQuery's [.ready( handler )](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Since you are including JQuery, you may then as well use it to set the height. Try [.height( function )](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height-function). In your case it would look like this:

```
$(".post-contain").height(function (index, height) {
    // Increase the height of all ".post-contain" divs
    return (height + 20);
});
```

All those combined together then yield the following:

```
$(function(){
    new MutationObserver(function (mutations){
        mutations.forEach(function (mutation){
            $(mutation.addedNodes).each(function (){
                if (this.localName == "a")
                    $(".post-contain",this).height(function (index, height){
                        return (height + 20);
                    });
            });
        });
    }).observe($("body")[0], {childList: true});
});
```

I have tested this on a local Meteor installation.

---

By the way, why do you need to add the height like this? You would then have to take of of other events, like [.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/). If you want the divs to have an extra height based on the content, why not to use CSS `padding` instead?

Comment: This seems like it should work, but it doesn't. There's no error either. The current version with your code is up if you want to check the changes I made.

Comment: I couldn't find any of the code from my proposed answer in the Meteor processed files at [http://whensayfeed.meteor.com](http://whensayfeed.meteor.com) . Maybe you could upload all the source codes from your meteor directory and link it here. It may be easier to find the problem that way.

Comment: Here's the complete source: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58842756/WhenISayFeed.zip

Comment: So I tested it locally. The callback of Template.myTemplate.onRendered actually executed before all the data were loaded. So replacing it with MutationObserver seemed as the simplest solution. I also found other SO questions regarding this particular problem.